# How to get view html and return to client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

below is code snippet which return view to jquery function but i like to know how could i extract or get the view html and return to client end.

```
$(function() {
   $('#myddl').change(function() {
       var url = $(this).data('url');
       var value = $(this).val();
       $('#result').load(url, { value: value })
    });
});

<div id="result"></div>
```

and inside the Foo action you could return a partial view:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string value)
{
    SomeModel model = ...
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

in web form this way i extarct the usercontrols or any controls related html.

```
System.Web.UI.Page pageHolder = new System.Web.UI.Page();
BBAReman.facebox.FeedBack ctl = (BBAReman.facebox.FeedBack)pageHolder.LoadControl("~/UserControls/FeedBack.ascx");
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm tempForm = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
tempForm.Controls.Add(ctl);
pageHolder.Controls.Add(tempForm);
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);
outputToReturn = output.ToString();
```

so how to do the same in mvc. just like to know how could i get the view html from action method. thanks

Comment: That Controller action that you `return PartialView` with is the way to do it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this method , passing the ActionResult from controller and getting back html from the view

```
    private string RenderActionResultToString(ActionResult result)
    {
        // Create memory writer.
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var memWriter = new StringWriter(sb);

        // Create fake http context to render the view.
        var fakeResponse = new HttpResponse(memWriter);
        var fakeContext = new HttpContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request,
            fakeResponse);
        var fakeControllerContext = new ControllerContext(
            new HttpContextWrapper(fakeContext),
            this.ControllerContext.RouteData,
            this.ControllerContext.Controller);
        var oldContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current = fakeContext;

        // Render the view.
        result.ExecuteResult(fakeControllerContext);

        // Restore old context.
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current = oldContext;

        // Flush memory and return output.
        memWriter.Flush();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, I was generating an html based report. I used this method to get the html which I could then turn into a pdf and save off.

Comment: what is `this` reference in this code @luca?
`new HttpContextWrapper(fakeContext),
            this.ControllerContext.RouteData,
            this.ControllerContext.Controller);`

Comment: @Behzad is a reference to your controller (the RenderActionResultToString method is an action of your controller)

Answer (score 1):

You can make an AJAX call to the MVC action method, which will return the partial view as HTML. You then simply call the `.html` jquery function to populate your div. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myddl').change(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var value = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "@Url.Action("Foo", "Controller")", // replace with your actual controller and action
      data: JSON.stringify({ value: value }),
      success: function(result) {
        $('#result').html(result);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you need a way to return raw HTML of your view to client side. If that's what you want you have to use the ViewEngine that MVC uses to render HTML.

Below is the sample :

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = null;

                viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
```

Above code finds a partial view and converts it into HTML String by MVC view engine.

Hope this helps.