# Get HTML of actionresult in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out how to get the HTML generated by an ActionResult in another class in my project. I am generating a complex HTML email template and rather than hardcoding the HTML as a string, I let the MVC engine do all the heavy lifting. Problem is I don't know how to get from ActionResult to raw HTML.

I also can't use WebClient().DownloadString(UrL) because for some reason the server the applicaiton is deployed to can't connect to the IP address the domain name is resolved to.

What I have is this:

```
string Res = new
Controllers.HomeController().GetCustomMailerTemplate(Al.SubscriptionToken);
```

unfortunately, I can't do much with the ActionResult object because it doesn't expose any useful methods or properties.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/18335997/2392330

Comment: Yes, dear. Google gives me lots of answers relating to JSON and JQuery, which is NOT what I want. But thanks for your comment.