# MVC : Get HTML string From Controller/Action, from a call from other controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view, render

I have a controller : TestController.cs

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return View();        
}

public string TestHtml()
{        
    //Get Result of Test as HTML string
    string HTMLString = "";

    ActionResult AR = Test();
    //Convert AR to HTML string

    HTMLString = ConvertActionResultToHtml(AR);

    //do something with HTMLString

    return HTMLString;
}
```

The Test() function has a view to it which returns a piece of HTML.

When i call the TestHtml() function i would like to get the same HTML but as a string, so i need the function "ConvertActionResultToHtml". Is there something like that.

I know there are MVC2mail components which do the same, render a View as Email.

When it can be done i would like to have a generic function to achive this. like :

```
public string GetHTMLFromControllerAction(string Controller, string Action) {
    //This function returns the result of a controller action as HTML string
    return ""; //
}
```

The code above i would like to call from another controller.

I tried the following code : 
[How to get view html and return to client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335402/how-to-get-view-html-and-return-to-client-side), but can't get it to work calling it from an another controller function.

Hope someone can help, or can give me any tips on an other sollution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

1 st - you need to install the RazorEngine in nugget package maneger;

Now you can use this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using RazorEngine.Configuration;
using RazorEngine.Templating;

namespace Test.ActionAsHtml.Models
{
    public class GetStringFromAction
    {
        private readonly static string _conventionFolderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Views");
        private readonly IRazorEngineService _razorEngineService;

    public GetStringFromAction()
    {
        var templateConfig = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
        {
            TemplateManager = new DelegateTemplateManager(controllerAndAction => File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(_conventionFolderPath, controllerAndAction))),
            DisableTempFileLocking = true,
            CachingProvider = new DefaultCachingProvider(t => { })
        };
        _razorEngineService = RazorEngineService.Create(templateConfig);
    }
    public string GetHTMLFromControllerAction(string controller, string action, object model)
    {
        //C# 6
        var actionController = $"{controller}/{action}.cshtml";
        //var actionController = string.Format("{0}/{1}.cshtml",controller,action);
        return _razorEngineService.RunCompile(actionController, model.GetType(), model); //
    }
}
```

}